# iPhone app submission (error reporting)

Tags: iphone

I have implemented silent error reporting (in background) for iPhone app by using try catch. This reports my server through webservice.

Do I need to notify the user if I am sending the error report. Will the app store reject if I do the silent error reporting.

Regards,
Malleswar

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether Apple will reject you.  Their standards are arbitrary and constantly changing.  However, if you don't notify the user, your program is essentially spyware.  It's the user's computer, and they deserve to know what the program does.

In practice, error data can sometimes reveal what the user was doing at the time of the error.

Answer (score 1):

It's very common to use analytics. You can't be sure which app do that and which don't. And yes, you can't be sure with Apple. To be in safe side, you can ask for permission once. If the user agree, then do it. Make the note to user something similar, "it's to make your experience better".

And yes, I agree that user should know what the app is doing.

Comment: Do you know any case which is rejected with that reasons?

Comment: No, I don't know any such case. In fact analytics is very common for big projects.